# Time based data query with Neo4J showing more relations than expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to get my mind around Neo4J and time based data.

So what I basically wanted to build is a data structure which is capable of giving me a tracking node (page view) with its referrer and its referrers-referrer on a certain time.

My problem is, that if I save data with its relations to the timetree there are still appearing relations which shouldn't be visible when querying a certain time by hour.

During research I found this article about [modeling time series data with neo4j](https://www.graphgrid.com/modeling-time-series-data-with-neo4j/).

So far all was well going but the referrer and its child relations were not abstracted by time.

To illustrate by problem better here comes first the data structure:

I created an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Year(value);
CREATE INDEX ON :Month(value);
CREATE INDEX ON :Day(value);
CREATE INDEX ON :Hour(value);
CREATE INDEX ON :Minute(value);
CREATE INDEX ON :Second(value);
```

And put there the time nodes:

```
//Create Time Tree with Day Depth
WITH range(2015, 2017) AS years, range(1,12) AS months
FOREACH(year IN years |
   CREATE (y:Year {value: year})
   FOREACH(month IN months |
     CREATE (m:Month {value: month})
    MERGE (y)-[:CONTAINS]->(m)
    FOREACH(day IN (CASE
                       WHEN month IN [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] THEN range(1,31)
                      WHEN month = 2 THEN
                        CASE
                          WHEN year % 4 <> 0 THEN range(1,28)
                           WHEN year % 100 = 0 AND year % 400 = 0 THEN range(1,29)
                           ELSE range(1,28)
                         END
                       ELSE range(1,30)
                     END) |
       CREATE (d:Day {value: day})
       MERGE (m)-[:CONTAINS]->(d))))
```

If i now save data:

```
MERGE (a:tracking {ip:'someniceid', type:'page_view', timestamp:'2154645'})
MERGE (f:Domain {name:'domain1.com'})
MERGE (e:Domain {name:'domain2.com'})
MERGE (d:Domain {name:'domain3.com'})
MERGE (z:Domain {name:'domain4.com'})
MERGE (a)-[:CAME_FROM]->(f)
MERGE (f)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(e)
MERGE (e)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(d)
MERGE (d)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(z)
WITH a, 2016 AS y 
MATCH (year:Year {value: y})
WITH a, year, 5 AS m 
MATCH (year)-[:CONTAINS]->(month:Month {value: m})
WITH a, month, 9 AS d 
MATCH (month)-[:CONTAINS]->(day:Day {value: d})
WITH a, day, 14 AS h 
MERGE (day)-[:CONTAINS]->(hour:Hour {value: h})
MERGE (a)-[:HAPPENED_ON]->(hour)
```

I get the following graph with query:

```
MATCH (y)-[:CONTAINS]->(m:Month {value: 5}) WITH y, m
MATCH (m)-[:CONTAINS]->(d {value: 9}) WITH y, m, d
MATCH (d)-[:CONTAINS]->(h {value: 14}) WITH y, m, d, h
MATCH (a:tracking)-[:HAPPENED_ON]->(h),(a)-[:CAME_FROM|:REFERRED_BY*]->(dom) RETURN dom AS D, a AS A
```

[image]

When I now save one more dataset with the only difference of changing the hour and domain (instead of domain4 we have now domain6) like:

```
MERGE (a:tracking {ip:'someniceid', type:'page_view', timestamp:'2154645'})"
MERGE (f:Domain {name:'domain1.com'})
MERGE (e:Domain {name:'domain2.com'})
MERGE (d:Domain {name:'domain3.com'})
MERGE (z:Domain {name:'domain6.com'})
MERGE (a)-[:CAME_FROM]->(f)
MERGE (f)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(e)
MERGE (e)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(d)
MERGE (d)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(z)
WITH a, 2016 AS y 
MATCH (year:Year {value: y})
WITH a, year, 5 AS m 
MATCH (year)-[:CONTAINS]->(month:Month {value: m})
WITH a, month, 9 AS d 
MATCH (month)-[:CONTAINS]->(day:Day {value: d})
WITH a, day, 10 AS h 
MERGE (day)-[:CONTAINS]->(hour:Hour {value: h})
MERGE (a)-[:HAPPENED_ON]->(hour)
```

So with the same query above one more referrer was added which to my opinion shouldnd happen because of the different time (hour) node related to the tracking node:

[image]

Referrer relations are shown in spite the tracking was connected to a different hour node! What did i do wrong? For me domain 6 shouldn't be visible because the related tracking was not connected with that time node... Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for each of the monitored events `merge` does not create a new record for the domain, and you have stored incorrect domain sequence. Try to create the links to domains for every tracking:

```
MERGE (a:tracking {ip:'someniceid', type:'page_view', timestamp:'2154645'})
MERGE (_f:Domain {name:'domain1.com'})
MERGE (_e:Domain {name:'domain2.com'})
MERGE (_d:Domain {name:'domain3.com'})
MERGE (_z:Domain {name:'domain4.com'})
CREATE (f:Symlink)-[:Symlink]->(_f)
CREATE (e:Symlink)-[:Symlink]->(_e)
CREATE (d:Symlink)-[:Symlink]->(_d)
CREATE (z:Symlink)-[:Symlink]->(_z)
MERGE (a)-[:CAME_FROM]->(f)
MERGE (f)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(e)
MERGE (e)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(d)
MERGE (d)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(z)
WITH a, 2016 AS y 
MATCH (year:Year {value: y})
WITH a, year, 5 AS m 
MATCH (year)-[:CONTAINS]->(month:Month {value: m})
WITH a, month, 9 AS d 
MATCH (month)-[:CONTAINS]->(day:Day {value: d})
WITH a, day, 14 AS h 
MERGE (day)-[:CONTAINS]->(hour:Hour {value: h})
MERGE (a)-[:HAPPENED_ON]->(hour)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have a question: would it also make sense to relate the domain to a time node in your opinion?

Comment: @Jurudocs I'm sorry, I did not understand your question. Can you explain?

Comment: lets say i want to get the total number of trackings for domain4.com would it make sense to relate each domain with an hour also like: (domain)-[:VISITED_ON]->(hour)?

Comment: @Jurudocs I think something like this: `MATCH p = (hour:Hour)<-[:HAPPENED_ON]-(a:tracking)-[:CAME_FROM|:REFERRED_BY*]->(s:Symlink)->(_z:Domain {name:'domain4.com'}) RETURN count(p)`